Using constant current driver and/or resistor for LED
I want to mount some high powered XHP LEDs to a PCB in parallel. If I'm using constant current drivers that are separate from the PCB to drive current into it at the rated voltage of the LEDs, would it be necessary to also connect every LED to a surface mount resistor on the PCB?

If you have a constant current driver it's better to pace the LEDs in series. Is there a reason you have to use a parallel connection?

Please add data sheet links to the LEDs and driver.

I want to mount some high powered XHP LEDs to a PCB in parallel. Bad idea. would it be necessary to also connect every LED to a surface mount resistor on the PCB? not if they all had their own current driver. If you are using a current sharing resistor per LED, you might as well use a voltage drive to the board. LEDs like a current drive down a series string, it's their happy place. If you're trying to voltage drive and current drive, you're probably wasting power, and certainly wasting brain strain.

The idea of a constant current driver is that you put all of the LEDs in series so that they all have the same current through them and assuming they’re all the same type they will all be very close to the same brightness.
The driver adjusts its output voltage to keep the current constant. There will be a limit of how many LEDs can be driven based on their forward voltage and the maximum voltage the driver can supply.
Because the current is limited by the driver no current limiting resistors are needed.
